# Sound coming from laptop when when headphones are connected Dell latitude 7440, ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pavucontrol

Since recently, when I have headphones plugged into my laptop, sound is not only coming from my headphones, but also from the laptop itself. The sound seems to be of a different quality/eq then when I am intentionally using the laptop speakers (it is in stereo though).
This could be related to a recent update, but I am not sure.

The only way I have been able to (partially) remedy it, is by turning off the sound from the BIOS. However, if I do that, it is not possible for me to play sound from the laptop speakers, and my headphone microphone no longer works (the laptop microphone does work)

Other things I have tried:

- reinstalled the latest kernel (linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic)
- reinstalled the latest firmware (linux-firmware=20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.26)
- followed by `sudo update-initramfs -u` and a reboot in both cases.

I have attached an image from alsamixer. As shown, sound will come out of the headphones and also the laptop.

I am unsure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

[alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znvhl.jpg)

Comment: Would `hdajackretask` be a good workaround for disabling (set to Not Connected) the laptop speakers?

Comment: @danielT Thanks for your reply! I had already been looking at `hdaanalyzer`, which I guess is a similar type of solution space. I had not yet been able to wrap my head around the routing with `hdaanalyzer` but I will take another look, and also see how it compares to `hdajackretask`.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on my Latitude 7440 2-in-1, Arch Linux, KDE Plasma, Linux 6.6.15-1-lts, Pipewire. USB-C headphones work as expected, only headphone jack is affected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (same device: Latitude 7440 with Ubuntu) and found a solution:

Once I downgraded the Dell BIOS firmware from 1.10.0 back to version 1.4.1, the issue was resolved (also tried to go "only" back to 1.9.1, but then the problem persisted).

You can download this older version of the BIOS firmware here (BIOS_IMG.rcv):
https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=kcp08&oscode=w2021&productcode=latitude-14-7440-2-in-1-laptop

Pull this file onto some USB drive.
Then reboot and press F12 while doing so, this opens one-time boot menu. Then you can choose "Flash the BIOS" (means update/downgrade), and "Flash the BIOS from file" or so.
Select the file from the USB drive, then start flashing process.

After the installation and another reboot, the audio issue you described should be resolved. (At least, that was the case for me.)